# WebGL Three.js : Texture alingment on a geometry face

Tags: html, 3d, three.js, webgl

I would like to write text on each faces of an IcosahedronGeometry

I'm able to generate the textures and apply the textures to all the faces :

```
for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {
geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = i;
materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { overdraw: true, map:  getTexture(i), wireframe: true, wireframeLinewidth: 1} ) );
 }

// 3D element   
element = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials) );
```

However each textures are overwriting the other ...  And I can't align them correctly

http://jsfiddle.net/jzbf7/

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how the UVs are set up for `IcosahedronGeometry` -- they are very similar to the UVs for `SphereGeometry`, in which a map of the world will cover the entire sphere.

This is very different from the UVs for `CubeGeometry`, where the texture maps to *each face*.

Experiment with the updated fiddle to see for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/jzbf7/2/ 
(If the sphere renders too dark, render it again -- the colors are random.)

Also, there is a bug in the `IcosahedronGeometry` UV map. This can be seen at the "seam".

three.js r.56

Comment: Thank-you for this adaptation, that means that there is no solution to apply text on a IcosahedronGeometry  faces ?

Comment: You can modify the IcosahedronGeometry UVs yourself to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: Thank-you, we will try to do this !